# Getting GTM code working on web application

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Our company uses a third party service for our career/job site, allowing users to submit applications for job postings. Initially, users land on an external facing platform which integrates nicely with GTM. Within the CMS, you can easily add GTM code to the header and body area. However, once a user clicks 'apply' on a job description, they're redirected to a web application, which is essentially a separate system. Unfortunately, this second system does not allow you to add code to the header or footer. I am, however, able to add code to the "thank you" page which users see when they submit an application.

On the "thank you" page, the only way to insert the GTM code is using a WYSIWYG. You cannot insert the code into the `<head>`, but you can insert it into the `<body>`. I know it's not ideal, but it's the only option.

Even though I can get the code to render on the page, it's not working at all. It's not recording pageviews, Google Tag Assistant doesn't see the code, and Google's GTM toolbar doesn't show up when the GTM container is in preview mode.

From what I can tell, the page does not refresh when a user submits an application. Thus, I'm assuming that is the reason why the tag is not working. I've tried using a number of different triggers, based on advice I've read online, but none have solved the issue.

I'm just using the standard GTM code, but I'll post my code below anyways:

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','###');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**NOTE:** I'm also utilizing the `<noscript>` code immediately after the `<script>` code.

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you publish the GTM container at least once?

Comment: @SomewhereDave yes, the container is currently firing on all pages outside of the web application.

Comment: Can you check if GTM and GA is laoded via console? In Chrome open Dev Tools, navigate to Network and search for gtm (There should be  an entry like gtm.js?id=GTM-ABC123) and collect.gifs for the sent hits. For GA its analytics.js. Also, if GTM and GA were loaded you should be able to fire hits manually by using ga("send", "pageview",location.pathname);

Comment: @SomewhereDave Nope, it doesn't appear to be loading. Also, I noticed that the files and scripts that were loaded did not change between the form page and the thank you page for the form. I assume that's as a result of the page not be refreshed when the form is submitted.

Comment: What happens is you add <script>alert(‘foo’)</script> to the page?

Comment: most probably they just remove `<script>` tags from published code.

Comment: @SomewhereDave It renders in code, but doesn't seem to do anything. Should I see a dialog box pop-up?

Comment: @zb' What do you mean?

Comment: I think, the data added by innerHtml from js, it will create element, but not run a script. Add iframe than, without noscript tag may be help.

Comment: No   pop ups.  There should be collect.gif entries in the network tab for sent hits. Did you check code injection as others mentioned? The thank you page is probably called via Ajax, which is why there are no changes.  Did David Bradshaws ideas help you out?

Comment: No   pop ups.  There should be collect.gif entries in the network tab for sent hits. Did you check code injection as others mentioned? The code probably doesn't change, because the thank you page is requested via Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the site you are trying to inject GTM into, takes steps to prevent you from adding JavaScript into their page.

This is a very common security measure on sites that allow users to add content to pages, as instead of GTM you could add something that attacks their server or place a bitcoin miner on the page.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection

Your only solutions to this is to ask your provider to support GTM directly, or if your lucky you may find the `<noscript>` version does work and that might be enough to meet your requirement.