# Is it possible to fire a pageview using an <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

This may be a dumb question, but is it possible to send GA or GTM data using an `<img>` tag? I've seen `<img>` tags used as conversion pixels, so I'm wondering if you could rig one up for Google tracking?

I posted previously about trying to implement tracking on a third party application. I can inject my GTM script without it being stripped, but it simply does not fire. I also tried removing GTM's `<noscript>` iframe out of the `<noscript>` tag so that it would fire by default. This did also not work.

Having said this, we currently have two third-party tracking pixels utilizing `<img>` tags on the same page that are firing correctly.

I don't need the GTM or GA code to do anything fancy, I merely want it to record a pageview, or fire an event.

View my previous post here: [Getting GTM code working on web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676508/getting-gtm-code-working-on-web-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (almost) not a problem. Construct your tracking request according to the specs for the [Measurement Protocol](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiGiJHArpvYAhXIF-wKHe9oARQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fdevguides%2Fcollection%2Fprotocol%2Fv1%2F&usg=AOvVaw0tt7T4ixwnEKfj4DVKo2kl). This will send a tracking request to GA and return a transparent 1x1 gif, so you can use that easily in an image tag. This works for both pageviews and events.

The small problem is that you may need to include some dynamic parameters - hostname, page path, and a browser specific client id that is used to aggregate hits into sessions (which means you also need a way to maintain the client id over multiple pageviews). So it probably will not work to just a static image, you need at least a bit of JS code to insert dynamic values into your tracking url.

Comment: So, if I just need to record a pageview, would something like `<img src="www.google-analytics.com?v=1&t=pageview">` work?

Comment: Obviously, I'd need to include my GA ID and all.

Comment: Sorry for all of the comments, but from what I understand, `<img>` tags only use the GET method, not POST, so I'm assuming Measurement Protocol would not work?

Comment: GET works just fine with the measurement protocol. Older browsers might have a smaller allowed payload size, so POST might be more safe, but you might just as well use GET. Use the hit builder to construct a valid tracking request and then past it to your browser console, you will see that there is not problem: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/